# How to edit a python file in eclipse when in C++ perspective?

Tags: python, eclipse-cdt

I use eclipse (cdt) for c++ projects. It contains some test scripts in python. Is there anyway I could get syntax highlighting and auto completion(if possible) when viewing a python script? Or should I load the complete python perspective?

Comment: I get syntax highlighting and auto-completion for python in both perspectives...

Answer (score 2):

You can just open your python file in the C/C++ perspective and get full syntax highlighting and auto completion.

- If that does not work for you, then perhaps you don't have PyDev installed. Find it and install it using `Help` > `Eclipse Marketplace`.
- If that still does not work for you (if you double-click it the file is opened as plain text, or gets executed in a command shell) then perhaps somehow the wrong editor got associated to it. Right click the file, then select `Open With` > `Python Editor`. You'll need to do this once: Eclipse will remember your choice.

---

Note: You can open any file in any perspective, and the corresponding editor will always open for you. A perspective is just a grouping of views that should be helpful for you in the given context. It does not enable or disable any additionally installed software.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to install PyDev... you should follow the getting started manual ( http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html ) which guides you from installing PyDev to running a Python file.